# display django fom from formset only when required

Tags: forms, django-forms, formsets

This might be simple but not able to get the work done.
here is a modelformset using which specific # of forms could be displayed:

```
formfact = formset_factory(ModelForm,extra = count)
fset = depffact(prefix='new')
```

My question is:
how can i display single form a time,how can i modify it such a way that everytime user
clicks a button previous forms are validated and one more modelform is displayed. 
i.,show form1,if asked for show #2,#3 etc

i tried keeping track of count and using that count but was not successful.Ideas most welcome

Answer (score 0):

by mistake i asked similar question twice
but i did answer it [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331489/adding-forms-from-formset-on-fly-from-server-side) incase if you want to refer. if you have a better solution, appreciate you sharing it.