# adding forms from formset on fly from server side

Tags: jquery, view, jquery-validate

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
    <div class="elements">
           {{form.as_ul}}
     </div>
     <input type="image" value="ADD" id="add_more">
{% endfor %}
```

here is what i have in js

```
$('#add_more').click(function(){
      if($('.app-form').valid()){
      cloneMore('div.ul:last','prefix');
    }
});
```

and the rest is same as the reference [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax?tab=votes#tab-top) I'm trying to display forms when user goes for "ADD".when add is pressed it goes to the view as well as print one more form using jquery.
in views.

```
  def start(request):
        qd = request.POST
        ffact = formset_factory(ModelForm,extra=int(qd['prefix-TOTAL_FORMS']))
        fset = ffact(qd,prefix='prefix')
        if fset.is_valid():
           return render_to_response('test.html',{'formset':fset})
        else:
           return render_to_response('test.html',{'formset':fset})
```

But jquery is resulting in additional form even if the submitted form is not valid,while view is resulting in the error messages for all the form-fields that are not valid.
How can i make click action wait or somehow communicate with the views.py validation result 
and only then display extra form? Appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have any code (HTML,JS) to start with?

Comment: i did update the question with that info.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could be done in two ways :either from user end or from backend but to my question NO.there is no way[i dint find one] to tie jquery/django for this purpose.
I'm trying to do the entire thing at server end:
in views.py:

```
query_dict = request.POST
tot = int(querydict['prefix-TOTAL_FORMS'])
   ffact = formset_factory(ModelForm,extra=tot)
   fset = ffact(query_dict,prefix='prefix')
   if fset.is_valid():
      ffact = formset_factory(ModelForm,extra=1)
      fset = ffact(initial=fset.cleaned_data,prefix='prefix')
      return render_to_response('test.html',{'formset':fset,})
```

in test.html:

```
{% for form in fset.forms%}
    {{form.as_ul}} or anything that works for you
{% endfor %}
```

this worked for me,there might be more efficient way. I'm more than happy to learn about it.